# React-backbone "griddle" rendering issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, datagrid, reactjs

Try to render react data grid component with data, which binded to backbone collection. But when I use usual global array it works properly. When I try to send to "griddle" the collection from the state it renders empty grid.

To be more briefly, I placed the question in comments of the code:

```
var fakeData =  [  // Usual global array of objects for test and example
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Mayer Leonard",
  },
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ivvy Leonard",
  }
];

var MyComponent = React.createClass({displayName: "MyComponent",

    // Use mixin to bind react class and backbone collection
    mixins: [backboneMixin], 
    // Next function testing of mixin's working. It's correct.
    createEntry: function (entry) {
        return React.createElement("div", {key: entry.id}, entry.id, " + ", entry.name);
    },

    fetch_btn: function() {
        this.props.collection.add({id:4, name: "Hello 4"});
    },
    getList: function(){
        var ar = this.state.collection;
        _l("ar = ", ar);
        return ar;
    },
    // Now the issue becoming
    render: function () {
        return (
            React.createElement("div", null,
                /* next code works fine, so the collection is valid,
                 also the collection have the same keys as fakeData */
                this.state.collection.map(this.createEntry), 
                React.createElement("input", {type: "button", value: "Fetch", onClick: this.fetch_btn}),
                /* next two rows are console.log wrappers and they show
                 that arrays are OK and similar */
                _l("react list",this.state.collection),
                _l("fake", fakeData),
                /* In this variant next code draws properly grid, but
                 if I change to {results: this.state.collection}
                 drawing function breaks and shows empty grid */
                React.createElement(Griddle, {results : fakeData})
            )
        );
    }
});
```

So if anybody helps, would appreciate it.

Comment: Try converting the collection to a regular javascript array before passing it to Griddle: 

 React.createElement(Griddle, {results : this.state.collection.toJSON()})